# Different behaviour when calling emit from class methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io

I am building an app with socket.io and typescript. As always I have created server and client but now I'm facing weird issue with my server code. My server is listening on 'connection' event and as callback creates new class instance and invokes his onConnect method. In this function it invokes another method - 'bindHandlers'. In this function socket listens to his events.

And this is my problem: if i pass callback to 'draw' event as an anonymous function it works as expected, but if i use my class method it sends events back to to the client instead of broadcasting it. I want to make my code more modular and this issue is blocking me for now.

main file:

```
io.on("connection", SocketService.createInstance(db).onConnect);
```

simplified socket file:

```
export class SocketService {
  private socket: Socket | null = null;

  constructor(private db: DB) {}

  static createInstance = (db: DB) => {
    return new SocketService(db);
  };

 onConnect = (socket: Socket) => {
   this.socket = socket;
   const username = socket.handshake.query.user;

   console.log(`${username} connected ${socket.id}`);

   this.bindHandlers(socket);
 };

  private bindHandlers = (socket: Socket) => {
   if (!this.socket) return console.log("socket is undefined");


   socket.on("draw", this.onDraw);
   // if I swap with code below it works properly
   // socket.on("draw", data => {
   //   socket.broadcast.emit("draw", data);
   // });
  };

 private onDraw = (data: DrawingPoint) => {
   const username = this.socket!.handshake.query.user;
   const { group } = data;

   this.socket!.broadcast.emit("draw", data);
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is working with:

```
socket.on("draw", data => {
  socket.broadcast.emit("draw", data);
});
```

is because you are using arrow function which for context (`this`) will have surrounding context, but when defining an event handler such as: `socket.on("draw", this.onDraw);` context will not be anymore instance of `SocketService`. Play with it a little bit and debug it to see what will be the context in a case when you are calling it with that.

One solution would be to set the context explicitly such as:
`socket.on("draw", this.onDraw.bind(this));`

Keep in mind that context of the method/function in JS depends on how method was called.

Comment: Oh yes, 'this' binding. I removed arrows and used binding inside my 'bindHandlers' procedure. Now it works correctly.